# Remove transcluded element in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive using button groups from Bootstrap. I'm using transclude so I can add in more buttons for certainly layouts. This all works like a champ, but I need to remove the transclude div so that it doesn't mess up the button group layout.

So the directive renders out this:

```
<div class="btn-group ng-isolate-scope">
<button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
<div ng-transclude="">
    <button class="btn btn-danger"Delete</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I want is this:

```
<div class="btn-group ng-isolate-scope">
<button class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```

I found [this article](http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html) but It's a bit outdated and references deprecated functions in compile. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us your directive either through a plunker or fiddle?